# PayPal in-context checkout - Acess Denied

Tags: paypal

We are implementing PayPal in-context checkout on our e-commerce site. Everything works fine in Chrome and FF but in IE11 the pop out window hangs on redirecting back to our site. Console show Access Denied error in PayPall app.js script on this piece of code:

```
if (window.miniBrowser && navigator.userAgent.match(/msie|trident/i)) {
        var bridge = window.opener.frames['PayPalBridge'];
        if (bridge && typeof(bridge) !== "undefined" && typeof(bridge.returnToParent) !== "undefined") {
            bridge.returnToParent(msg);
        }
    } else {
        window.opener.postMessage(msg,"*");
    }
```

I switched all security levels to lowest possible, tried to add both sites (ours and sandbox.paypal.com) to Trusted zone but it didn't help. Any ideas what can be wrong or how can we work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad. Didn't setup PayPal module properly. Environment info was missing so PayPal assumed production while generating IFrame. As I was using sandbox on my test site it resulted with cross-domain operation which was blocked by IE.